# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\mysites\nametestclonescript\includes\core.php on line 95

Tags: php, warnings

I got this error on my code.

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in
>   C:\XAMPP\htdocs\mysites\namescript\includes\core.php on line
>   95

This is the code on which the error is shown..

```
               95.   $Test['time'] = time() - $Test['time'];
               96.   if($LIMIT != 3){
               97.      $LIMIT++;
               98.        }else{
               99.          if($Test['time'] > 86400){
               100.             $Is_New = false;
               101.             }                   
               102.        }
```

I am using php 7.1. Can anyone help me to resolve this error without removing the line. I am a starter in php.
Thank you

Comment: What is in `$Test['time']` ? `var_dump()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast `$Test['time']` to int, it will return 0 if `$Test['time']` is empty or non-numeric:

```
$Test['time'] = time() - ((int)$Test['time']);
```